# Zend- How to read the contents of the uploaded file

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, zend-form

I am uploading a file and now I want to read the contents of that file. But I am getting

```
array(0) {
}
```

What I am doing wrong in this code?

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
            try {
                $adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
                $adapter->addValidator('Count', false, array('min' => 1, 'max' => 3))
                        ->addValidator('Size', false, array('max' => 10000))
                        ->addValidator('Extension', false, array('extension' => 'csv', 'case' => true));

                $adapter->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH ."/../public/tmp/upload");

                $files = $adapter->getFileInfo();
                echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($files);

                foreach($files as $fieldname    =>  $fileinfo) {
                    if (($adapter->isUploaded($fileinfo['name'])) && ($adapter->isValid($fileinfo['name']))){
                        echo $path   =   $fileinfo['destination'].'/'.$fileinfo['name'];
                        chmod($path, 0777);
                        var_dump($adapter->receive($path));

                    }
                }

                var_dump($adapter->getMessages());
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo "Exception!\n";
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Example #3 in https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html it says you can use the getfileName() method, then just do a file_get_contents() on the file.

```
 $filename = array_pop($adapter->getFileName());
 $file_contents = file_get_contents($filename);
```